# Problem with rotating a two-dimensional array in python

Tags: python

How to to make this array rotate by 90 degrees to right without using numpy.

```
multiarray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
auxiliaryArray = []
colLength = len(multiarray[0])
rowLength = len(multiarray)
for indexRow in range(len(multiarray)):
    for indexCol in range(len(multiarray[0])):
        auxiliaryArray[indexCol][rowLength - 1 - indexRow] = multiarray[indexRow][indexCol]

print(auxiliaryArray)
```

Error:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Desired Output: `[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]`

Comment: instead of making an empty `list`, initialize a `list` with zeroes or some other values, that way you can't get out of range error

Comment: if you are looking at mathematic way without using additional library you can read this. https://integratedmlai.com/matrixinverse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` on the reversed array:

```
auxiliaryArray = list(zip(*multiarray[::-1]))
```

or

```
auxiliaryArray = list(zip(*reversed(multiarray)))
```

output: `[(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]`

If you need lists and not tuples:

```
auxiliaryArray = list(map(list, zip(*reversed(multiarray))))
```

output: `[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]`

Comment: Could it be done with append?

Comment: Why? Is this an assignment?

Comment: Something like that

Comment: I take this as a yes… Yes it can be done, but you should have made it explicit from the beginning that it was an assignment (cf. SO guidelines), your question wouldn't have been closed

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
list(zip(*multiarray[::-1]))
```